# pointer-events:none on embed/object in and out of iframe browser inconsistencies/bugs

Tags: css, object, iframe, embed

I need to have pointer-events: none on a youtube video to allow clicking of the parent div. Not being able to interact with the video is required behaviour. Check out the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/annam/ZrCkR/1/

```
.test iframe, .test object, .test embed {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

The first test, using the iframe option, works perfectly on firefox, but on chrome the event doesn't get called. It seems like most of the items in the iframe do respect the pointer-events: none, all apart from the embed object itself, which even though on click, the video doesnt start playing, it absorbs the mouse events. In the real scenario, also have the parent div draggable, and in chrome on first click the video starts dragging, with no way to stop.

The second test case, using the old embed code, works fine on chrome, triggering the event, but on firefox it's like pointer-events:none is not there, with the video being fully interactable.

The same thing seems to happen with vimeo videos, so it seems to be generic browser behaviour for embeds

Any ideas how to overcome these issues or why these inconsistencies exist?